# Is there a combined Fitness/RPG site?

Tags: websites

I'm looking for a fitness site which would motivate me by letting me enter my workouts, and then reward me with progress in some kind of game. Is there such a site out there?

Fitocracy does not qualify since you only get points and there's no actual game.

Comment: Like that idea. Unfortunately, could never have a competitive game as you know people would cheat, but some kind of digital representation of yourself would be neat - maybe a superhero or a warrior or something.

Comment: @Yatrix It could be either a single-player game, or a casual MMO.

Comment: @Tim Totally agree. I just don't think you could have it competitive because where there's opportunity for cheaters to ruin something, they will take it. I guess if you're just doing it as a reward to yourself for doing well in the gym, then the competition won't matter to you. I just couldn't - I abhor cheaters. =)

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in checking out ["ZOMBIES, RUN!"](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sixtostart/zombies-run-a-running-game-and-audio-adventure-for)

They are a Kickstarter project that combines GPS run tracking with an RPG-like soundtrack for while you run. It is already funded (they got $72,627 of their $12,500 goal) so you will have to wait for awhile. But, you can get more details, pre-order, and watch a concept video on [their site](http://www.zombiesrungame.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[FitRPG](http://lifehacker.com/fitrpg-turns-your-fitbit-into-a-game-you-play-with-frie-1602140820) fits your bill, I think. There is no storyline (their Kickstarter to add one failed to fund), but you do get to upgrade your character.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase that you want to look for is "gamification", it's a somewhat new field of study in motivation, and it's basically how to apply game concepts such as higher reputation, achievement badges, privileges for higher rep players (Does this system sound familiar? :) ) to everyday concepts from play to work and achieve higher work levels and output.

http://wellnessforce.com/resource/7-best-gamification-fitness-apps-for-2015/

That is one of the first hits when searching google for fitness gamification apps, and includes FitRPG as recommended above, as well as a couple others. I know that there are a LOT of cyclists and triathletes that use Strava as a motivating tool, so you just need to find the app and community that fits your interests.